# How to get the method's parameter expression stack or string representation?

Tags: java, reflection

I am writing a method for debugging and metrics capturing, such that:

```
void capture(Object value, String debugName) {
  System.out.println("captured " + debugName + " with value " + value);
}
```

and calling it with:

```
capture(foo.bar(), "foo.bar");
```

Is there any way to get the value expression string directly, so I don't need to pass the debugName? Something like:

```
void capture(Object value) {
  System.out.println("captured " + getStack(value) + " with value " + value);
}
```

Comment: No. What ends up in `Object value` is whatever `foo.bar()` evaluated to.

Comment: Does ```Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()``` meet your demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could use the stack to figure out something about the `foo.bar()` call is to run that `capture()` code from within the `bar()` method itself, i.e. some AOP framework or some `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`-based approach to inject your code into `bar()` itself.

The stack of `capture()` in your example can never hint at `foo.bar()`, but to whatever method called `capture`. If you make `foo.bar()` invoke it, you can get the `TypeOfFoo.bar()` information from `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]`.

However, there's no way to figure out the name `foo` (in your example), so you would have to live with `captured TypeOfFoo.bar() with value ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can log where `capture` was called:

```
public class Test {
    public static void capture(Object value) {
        Exception e = new Exception();
        System.out.println("captured value " + value + " at " + e.getStackTrace()[1]);
    }

    public static void someFunc() {
        capture("alice");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        capture("fred");
        someFunc();
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
captured value fred at Test.main(Test.java:25)
captured value alice at Test.someFunc(Test.java:21)
```